# Error in linked lists function in python

Tags: python

I have to Convert a number into linked list such that each digit is in a node and pointing to node having next digit.The function should return head of the linked list. e.g input 120 should create a list of Nodes 1 -> 2 -> 0 and return the reference.If it is a negative number say -120 it should return -1->-2->0.I tried to do it in this way:

```
def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    for x in str(number):
        if x<0:
           x = -int(x)
           node = Node(int(x))
        else:
           node = Node(int(x))
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
    return head
    pass
```

It is working fine for positive numbers but if I pass -120.It is showing an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'.
```

How can I fix it.

Comment: If you're iterating through the characters in the string representation of a number and calling `int()` on each, you'll need to special-case "-", because it's not an integer.

Comment: My function call is this:'head = number_to_list(-120)'@Wooble

Comment: Isn't this basically your other question asked again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532916/error-in-linked-lists-function-in-python#21532916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str(-120) return '-','1','2','0'

try this:

```
    needMinus = number < 0
    for x in str(abs(number)):
        if needMinus:
            x = -int(x)
            needMinus = False
            node = Node(int(x))
        else:
            node = Node(int(x))
        if head:
            tail.next = node

        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are iterating over a string

```
for x in string(number):
```

Makes x a character, which iterates over the string number. Now when you have a positive number, each digit in the number can be converted to an int. But when you pass a negative number, x takes the value of '-' which cannot be converted to an integer. There you get the error. By what I see, I think you are storing the absolute values of the digits of the  numbers in the list. This can be done by checking if the character is '-', where you can just give a `pass` to do nothing in this iteration.

```
if x=='-':
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration with negative number you actually do:

```
int('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a line of code to check for '-' (and possibly '.'  if you allow decimal values.)

```
if(x=='-'):
    # Mark the number as negative
    negative = True
    # Move on to the next character
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a negative number this `int('-')` is called in the first iteration. You can keep a boolean flag through which you can identify if a number is positive or negative.

Example: 
Note: I have not tested this code. This code is just to give an idea

```
  def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    positive = True
    for x in str(number):
        if x=='-':
           positive = False
           continue
        else:
          if postive:
             node = Node(int(x))
          else:
             node = Node(int("-"+x))
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
    return head
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string of non (base 10, by default) integer gives a `ValueError`:

```
In [1034]: int('-')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1034-4c2a77a1869c> in <module>()
----> 1 int('-')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

likewise, `int('10L'), int('0x1a'), int('abc'),` etc.

You can treat `number` as a positive, and then add a negative sign to each single digit if `number` is actually a negative:

```
def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    if number<0: number=-number
    sign=-1 if number<0 else 1

    for x in str(number):
        node = Node(sign*x)

        if head:
            tail.next = node
        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
    return head
    pass
```